# Namespace setting of RoR route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, namespaces

If I set the following content in the route, will the two "projects" be the same? (Such as Controller and View)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :projects

  namespace :admin do
    resources :projects
  end

end
```

Comment: No.  But you can discover what they will be if you run `rails routes | grep admin` in the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the two "projects" will not be same. For first one controller and views will be in the main folder and for 2nd one the controller and view will lie under the admin folder in directory.
Also, the routes for first one will be like --
for index -- /projects
and for 2nd one
for index -- /admin/projects